# Rowspan on Bootstrap 4 Beta 0 Grid System

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

Hi I'm working on a eCommerce template witch uses Bootstrap 4 Beta. I made it work on mobile, but on desktop I could not figure how to make the Buy Box stay under title. On my aproach it apears under the Gallery section.

Desired Desktop
[image: Desktop Layout]

Desired Mobile
[image: Mobile Layout]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-1 d-none d-md-block"></div>
        <div class="col-xl-10 col-12">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xl-6 order-xl-1 col-12 order-2 d-flex">
                   Gallery
               </div>
               <div class="col-xl-6 order-xl-2 col-12 order-1">
                   Title
               </div>
               <div class="col-xl-6 order-xl-3 col-12 order-3">
                   Buy Box
               </div>
               <div class="col-12  order-xl-4  order-4">
                   Description
               </div>
               <div class="col-12  order-xl-5 order-5">
                   Related
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-1 d-none d-md-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the util classes to float the cols on `xl` widths, which would cause the "Best Buy" box to move under the title, assuming the height of the gallery is taller.

https://www.codeply.com/go/3E3Y9A5zZa

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-1 d-none d-md-block"></div>
        <div class="col-xl-10 col-12">
           <div class="row d-xl-block d-flex h-100">
               <div class="col-xl-6 order-xl-1 col-12 order-2 order-xl-1 d-flex bg-warning tall float-left">
                   Gallery
               </div>
               <div class="col-xl-6 order-xl-2 col-12 order-1 bg-primary float-left">
                   Title
               </div>
               <div class="col-xl-6 order-xl-3 col-12 order-3 bg-primary float-left">
                   Buy Box
               </div>
               <div class="col-12 bg-info order-4 float-left">
                   Description
               </div>
               <div class="col-12 bg-info order-5 float-left">
                   Related
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-1 d-none d-md-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @ZimSystem, I tried on my layout and it worked very well. Thanks for your attention and quick answer.