# How to make specific css layout different for mobile and desktop view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I need to make a layout with different order for mobile and desktop view.
For desktop view I need:

```
[ 2 ][ 1 ]
[ 2 ][ 3 ]
```

Height of all blocks can be different. It is important that the second block is on the left, and the first and third on the right, one under one.

For mobile:

```
[ 1 ]  
[ 2 ]
[ 3 ]
```

I'm using bootstrap 3 for the layout, but it does not help much. I literally broke my head, trying to do it. Maybe I do not see anything obvious?

**UPDATED**
With a bootstrap, I can push or pull two blocks to rearrange them on large screens, but I do not understand how to place third  under the first on the right side

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">2</div>
  <div class="??? how-to ???">3</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying flexbox

```
.wraper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  @media (min-width: @screen-md) {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    .second {
      order: -1;
      width: 70%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .first, .third{
      width: 30%;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool community, minus the question without even reading it. I tried a lot of options and through the bootstrap, and through the flexbox. None of this gave me the right solution. I've been googling for quite some time and looked for stackoverflow, I did not find anything like it, unfortunately.
Asking the question, I hoped that someone might have a ready-made solution. I doubt that the attached tons of failed attempts can somehow solve my problem.

Comment: and what you have tried? Put your code first we can help you (you should write media query)

Comment: have you tried the grid system this should help ...https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/

Comment: Check this Question. It may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905645/rowspan-on-bootstrap-4-beta-0-grid-system

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks, to Suresh Ponnukalai. He pushed me to an obvious solution with an old good 'float'

```
@media (min-width: @screen-md) {
  .second {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
  }

  .first, .third{
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```